# How to tell dpkg to hold packages based on name pattern

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, dpkg

An unattended upgrade broke my nvidia driver and I had to remove and reinstall the correct driver. I'd like to prevent this from happening again in the future.
This is what was upgraded according to `/var/log/apt/history.log`

```
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64 (1:1.1.9-1.1, automatic)
Upgrade: libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), nvidia-compute-utils-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), nvidia-dkms-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), nvidia-driver-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), nvidia-utils-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), nvidia-kernel-common-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), nvidia-kernel-source-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-compute-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1, 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
```

I'd like to tell dpkg to hold all upgrades related to nvidia, but everything I can find only shows how to do it for one specific package (e.g. `echo "<package-name> hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`). How do I do this for packages including a pattern (e.g. nvidia)?

Comment: Please file a proper bug report. Security updates installed by Unattended Upgrades should not cause breakage.

Comment: @user535733 where should I report this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug . Bugs that are not reported generally won't get fixed.

Comment: Will look into this thank you. At the mean time figured out the way to do this is to create a config file and black list nvidia https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades